# ClientDataSet: Store data in the order they are appended

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

It seems, when I append data to the TClientDataSet they are not stored in the sequence I have appended them. Sometimes they are and sometimes not. Is there an option to have the data in the same sequence, as I e.g. read them from a file or Database?

I want to avoid creating a separate column to store the position and set an index on them.

Comment: No, it isn't possible.

Comment: I don't think it needs a down vote. Its a reasonable question, intelligibly asked.

Comment: This is the nature of just about any database engine. SQL Server works this way even. Don't you have some sort of ID field with auto-incrementing numbers? I've never relied on auto-sorting for this exact reason. Only you know how you want it to be sorted, that's not automatic.

Comment: that is dataset implementation dependent. for example with my TVClientDataSet appended records always stored at the end of storage so you get what you describe without setting any option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With databases and this includes the TClientDataset, you can never assume that the data will come out of the database in the order you put them in, or in any particular order.

If order is important, use another column to store the insertion order, or deduce the order from another column.

One of the reasons this happens is that the database, when a row is deleted, doesn't "bunch" up the other rows to fill the gap, but re-uses the gap when a new record is added.

There is an ftAutoInc field type that can be used with TClientDataset, so there isn't much work to do to look after the new column.

Comment: that is dataset implementation dependent

Comment: It is, but a good rule of thumb to work to.  Every database and dataset I have worked on has exhibited this behaviour.  I never rely on the natural ordering of data coming out of a data store. Regards,

Comment: that doesn't mean there are no exceptions. so sometimes one can assume that the data will come out of the database in the order one put them in

Comment: @vavan yes you're right.  Maybe you should name a few that behave in that way so we can use them on our next projects.  The question referred to TClientDataset which does not guarantee the order data comes out and I make the point that it is common for databases to behave in that way.  I'll be genuinely interested in your list. Regards,

Comment: I already mentioned my own TVClientDataSet but I'm afraid you won't be able to use it your next projects. btw CDS is not quite database but rather in-mem records storage. I have no such list but quite sure there are other datasets retaining record order available